# Exact Functors and Elementary Embeddings

Tags: category-theory, set-theory, large-cardinals

One of the possible equivalent definitions of measurable cardinals defines them to be the critical point of an embedding of the universe $V$ into a transitive class $M$. Recently I learned of Trnková and Blass' result (see [here](https://msp.org/pjm/1976/63-2/pjm-v63-n2-p03-s.pdf)) that the existence of a measurable cardinal is equivalent with the existence of an exact functor on the category of sets not naturally isomorphic to the identity.

I was wondering whether these two concepts - exact functors on sets, and elementary embeddings - are connected in a deeper way. Moreover, I was wondering if there are similar results connecting other large cardinals with preservation results for functors.

Comment: What does "exact" mean in the context of Blass's result? Is it preservation of finite limits and colimits? It's not exactness in the sense of Barr, right?

Comment: Yes, preservation of finite limits and colimits!